# Eclipse+Node.js error when debugging: "Failed to connect to Standalone V8 VM connect timed out"

Tags: eclipse, node.js

Here is how I've done:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger

but in the image after "Now start making new debug configuration by clicking the “New” button:"

my image is different.

However when I run the debug I get the "Failed to connect to Standalone V8 VM connect timed out" error;

**In the debug configuration I never set the main file to run when the server starts. so something must be missing...**

I have another little question...

when I run the "node --debug dbgtest.js" code it works... what I'm doing it wrong?

**thanks a lot**

Comment: Related question for Nodeclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877014/node-js-express-app-wont-start-or-debug-in-eclipse-nodeclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. Of course the debugger will fail to connect if you are not running your `node --debug dbgtest.js`, which defaults to port 5858. It simply can’t connect then.

You can specify different ports: `node --debug[=port] dbgtest.js`, as it also says in the beginning of the wiki link.

Comment: thanks I think that solved my problem. Since then I've already figured a way to do.. thanks anyway (:

Comment: hmmm...but how do I debug from a session running in the browser? It seems when I debug from Eclipse, there is no node.js server running on localhost. But I want to debug that localhost session...

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with the latest versions of node being incompatible with the Eclipse JDST node.js debugger.

I get the same error in Eclipse when using node 8.9.4.  Tried a lot of things in Eclipse, nothing worked.

So I tried a node.js release from mid-2016, version 4.8.7.  This was released around the time when the Eclipse JSDT/node integration was announced (http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2016/may/article3.php).  That version of node.js works fine with the latest Eclipse releases.

It's probably something minor that is getting in the way.  The latest version produces the message: "DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead."  It's given as a warning, but perhaps this is what is the underlying issue, perhaps node.js gives up when seeing --debug.  Unfortunately, I cannot see how this could be changed in Eclipse without changing the code.

The latest version of node that works is version 7.  Starting with 8.0.0, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

With nodejs version 8 the old debug-interface was removed and a new interface took it's place that's controlled via `--inspect` instead of `--debug`.

AFAIK there is no eclipse plugin that uses the new interface. Debugging can now be done using the chrome-browser, just search the www for "Debugging Node.js with Google Chrome"