# node.js express app won't start (or debug) in Eclipse (Nodeclipse)

Tags: eclipse, node.js, debugging, express, nodeclipse

When I do on my app.js `Debug As > Node Application` it says

```
Launching STANDALONE_V8 has encountered a problem.
Failed to connect to Standalone V8 VM
connect timed out
```

It should start an app. Doing so directly on my terminal works fine. 
When I start a debug session in my terminal and than try to debug it in Eclipse works fine too.

So is there anything that has to be done in order to make it work in Eclipse?

Comment: Could you please share exact steps you take, that succeeded.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any luck?

Comment: There may be many reason, one is to check Preference, other is related to used Java https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/72

Answer (score 0):

What exact error is in ErrorLog View on in Nodeclipse Console?
What is Java is used and Nodeclipse version?

Try to specify Java version: in eclipse.ini point to JDK 7

Check also
- [toggleBreakpointsTargetFactory specified id is already registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689501/togglebreakpointstargetfactory-specified-id-is-already-registered)